# HELP - Ford Focus Oil Change

Tags: oil, oil-change, stuck-bolt

So the oil in my 2008 Ford Focus needs changed. Usually no problem, but the last shop I took it to over torqued the bolt and stripped it as well. I've tried using "Liquid Wrench" as well as various sizes of wrenches and its not moving at all. I've even tried removing the drain bolt when the car was cool and when it was warmed up a little. I'm starting to lose my mind over this and just getting so frustrated. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting a good grip on the plug, or are your tools slipping?

Comment: When you say 'stripped it' , presumably you mean they rounded the head of the bolt, not stripped the threads?

Answer (score 4):

You have three options; work on the bolt to remove it (possibly drilling it out, etc), remove the entire sump and order a replacement (they are surprisingly inexpensive) or change the oil with a pela style suction pump that extracts the old oil without removing the sump plug.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds wrong, but the best solution is to take it to a dealer for an oil change. The cost isn't that much (often, cheaper than the oil change stores out there), and they'll get that plug out. They will then put a new plug in if needed; yes, you'd have to pay for it, but you'd have to buy one anyway if the old one was destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. They've worked for me. 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIIp5.jpg)

Comment: A bit more explanation may be helpful...